# Lerna [version 2.9] cannot add external dependencies without breaking app

Tags: npm, npm-install, lerna

New to lerna, and the current repo I am working in is running lerna 2.9 so cannot find docs going back to 2.9 version. Below is my set up
App
    /node_modules
    /packages 
        /repo1
        /repo2
        /repo3
    package.json

repo1 is injecting some html into repo 2 (which is a react app), repo1 is has some dependencies coming from repo 3. When I try to install a dependency in repo 1 using **lerna add --scope="@app/my-package" dependency** I can no longer start my react app (repo 2) because repo 1 breaks and is unable in import repo 3.

What is the proper method to adding external dependencies to my internal package using lerna?

command suggested here is for lerna 3.x https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/add#readme

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to add a dependency from one local package to another? Asking because it looks to me like you are missing something in the example command: `lerna add <package> - -scope="@app/my-package"`

Comment: Im on the newest version of lerna so not sure I can help, but I can point you to the source of 2.9: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/releases/tag/v2.9.0 which I assume includes documentation

Comment: @cYrixmorten, I am trying to add a new dependency to a package. I've looked at the link you provided, it does not give any information on how to add a package for version 2.9

Comment: If it is a regular dependency from npm then just do npm install as you normally would while in `my-package` dir.

Comment: that was step one, tried that and it failed. On the other hand, doing npm install defeats the purpose of using lerna.

Comment: Ok, but no, not at all. Lerna allows keeping multiple projects in a single repo, doing npm install on individual projects makes perfect sense. Think I need more info on how it fails in order to be able to help out.

Comment: Did you do `lerna bootstrap` after installing a dependency, that could be what is missing